# How to JSON encode multi-dimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I am creating a array for posting candidate details to an API.
that API accepts data in JSON format, I am creating a data for the API using PHP array and using JSON encode to convert it JSON array. but not able to get intended format

**PHP Code**

```
$postArray = array(
      "DefaultCurrency" => "USD",
      "UserName" => "data",
      "Photograph" => "data",
      "PhotographThumb" => "data",
      "Group" => "data",
      "Summary" => "data",
      "ResumeText" => "data",
      "RollupListMembership" => array(
          "RollupCode" => "data"
        ),
      "CustomFields" =>  array(
          "FieldName" => "Major",
          "Values" => array(
            $finalResumeData-> "data"
          ),
          "FieldName" => "Years of Experience",
          "Values" => array(
            $MonthsOfWorkExperience
          ),
          "FieldName" => "Executive Type",
          "Values" => array(
            $finalResumeData-> "data"
          ),
        )
    );
```

**If i run this code as it is its showing only last result of the CustomFields**

I have tried using `array()` for individual **CustomFields** in the array like

```
"CustomFields" =>  array(
          array("FieldName" => "Major",
          "Values" => array(
            $finalResumeData-> "data"
          )),
```

I am getting the results as

```
CustomFields: {
    "0": {
        "FieldName" : "Value",
        "Values": ["data"]
    }
}
```

**Intended result**

```
"CustomFields": [
    {
      "FieldName": "string",
      "FieldType": "string",
      "Values": [
        "string"
      ]
    },
    {
      "FieldName": "string",
      "FieldType": "string",
      "Values": [
        "string"
      ]
    }
],
```

So what should I update in the PHP array to get intended results.

Comment: You can't have multiple values in a PHP array with the same key (`FieldName` and `Values`).

Comment: @Nick, Yes that is exact first issue I have notices but after wrapping each element with array(); like 

`"CustomFields" =>  array(
          array("FieldName" => "Major",
          "Values" => array(
            $finalResumeData-> "data"
          )),`

I am getting the results as 0, 1... keys but I want it to be
`{
      "FieldName": "string",
      "FieldType": "string",
      "Values": [
        "string"
      ]
    }`

Comment: You should not be getting numeric keys in your JSON, unless you specify it as an option. What is your exact `json_encode` call?

Comment: @jh1711 its `$putdata = stripslashes(json_encode($postArray));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside "CustomFields" you're repeating the same keys again within one array, so they will just overwrite each other. Instead you need an array of separate objects (represented by associative arrays in PHP), i.e. just the same structure as you've shown in your desired JSON output.

```
"CustomFields" =>  array(
      array(    
           "FieldName" => "Major",
          "Values" => array(
            $finalResumeData->data
          )
     ),
     array(
          "FieldName" => "Years of Experience",
          "Values" => array(
            $MonthsOfWorkExperience
          )
     ),
     array(
          "FieldName" => "Executive Type",
          "Values" => array(
            $finalResumeData->data
          )
    ),
)
```

N.B. This assumes you're using `json_encode($postArray);` without any extra options.

Demo: https://eval.in/1059736

Comment: To reply to your (now deleted) comment to my (now deleted) comment. Yes, you are correct, I misread their code.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions

Answer (score 2):

I have just modified your code little bit and getting the output you wanted.

```
$postArray = array(
  "DefaultCurrency" => "USD",
  "UserName" => "data",
  "Photograph" => "data",
  "PhotographThumb" => "data",
  "Group" => "data",
  "Summary" => "data",
  "ResumeText" => "data",
  "RollupListMembership" => array(
      "RollupCode" => "data"
    ),
  "CustomFields" =>  array(
      array("FieldName" => "Major",
      "Values" => array(
        'dsadas'=> "data"
      )),
      array("FieldName" => "Years of Experience",
      "Values" => array(
        'rewrew'=>'dsa'
      )),
      array("FieldName" => "Executive Type",
      "Values" => array(
        'test'=> "data"
      )),
    )
);


echo "<pre>";print_r($postArray);
echo json_encode($postArray);
?>
```

Here is the output I am getting.

```
{  
  "DefaultCurrency":"USD",
  "UserName":"data",
 "Photograph":"data",
 "PhotographThumb":"data",
 "Group":"data",
 "Summary":"data",
 "ResumeText":"data",
 "RollupListMembership":{  
  "RollupCode":"data"
},
"CustomFields":[  
   {  
      "FieldName":"Major",
      "Values":{  
         "dsadas":"data"
      }
   },
   {  
      "FieldName":"Years of Experience",
      "Values":{  
         "rewrew":"dsa"
      }
   },
   {  
     "FieldName":"Executive Type",
     "Values":{  
        "test":"data"
     }
   }
  ]
}
```

Comment: @WasimSayyed this is basically identical to my answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/52516751/5947043) posted 10 minutes earlier, but without the benefit of a live demo or any actual explanation of the problem, yet you accept and upvote this, and ignore mine? There's nothing wrong with this answer per se (although I wouldn't upvote a code-only answer personally), but it's just a duplicate of an earlier one.

Comment: @WasimSayyed I'm not sure what you mean? I posted a **live demo** which **proves** that it solves the issue. And if I didn't think it solved the issue, I wouldn't write an Answer - what would be the point of that?